# Angularjs: Transfer data from <select> to lists

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In angular, how would I change this selection to a list while maintaining the same functionality and data?

```
<select ng-if="main.fbWriteup.data"
          name="selectGroup"
          class="form-control"
          ng-model="main.selectedGroup"
          ng-options="key as key for (key,group) in main.fbWriteup.data"
          ng-change="main.selectedMessage=-1">
  </select><br/>
```

here is my full code: http://codepen.io/Zancrash/pen/KVYdqP/

You can add a group and the groups added are displayed within the dropdown menu. But I want all of them to be shown as a list item instead.

Comment: What do you exactly want? After you've entered something in the prompt, should it be added to the select dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I know what you're looking for.

I've created a new demo fiddle because your code is hard to read.

Just use `ng-repeat` to loop over your list of groups and add `ng-click` for selecting the group.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/uhtmebd3/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
 .controller('mainController', MainController);
  
function MainController($scope) {
 var vm = this,
    defaultEntries = [{
       id: 0,
       name: 'group1'
      },{
       id: 1,
       name: 'group2'
    }];
 angular.extend(vm, {
   groups: defaultEntries,
    selectedGroup: defaultEntries[0],
    addGroup: function() {
      var newGroupName = prompt('enter group name'),
        newItem = {id: vm.groups.length+1, name: newGroupName}
      vm.groups.push(newItem);
      vm.selectedGroup = newItem; // select new item
   }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController as ctrl">
<button ng-click="ctrl.addGroup()">
Add Group
</button>

<select ng-model="ctrl.selectedGroup" ng-options="group as group.name for group in ctrl.groups"></select>
group selected: {{ctrl.selectedGroup}}

<h1>
Group list
</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="group in ctrl.groups"><a href="#" ng-click="ctrl.selectedGroup = group">{{group.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```